# dashboard to show eventlog errors, warnings (traces) etc.

Tags: iis, windows-event-log

i'm after a dashboard (tfs?) to show what's currently going on with my MVC website. We write errors to the event log, and I duplicate that to a trace which I'm displaying 'live' with dbgview but I'm after something a bit more polished. What should I be using? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of products out there (both commercial and free) that collect event logs (and log files) and allow you to create dashboards and custom searches.

Since you're running Windows you can take a look at [EventSentry](https://www.eventsentry.com) - has a flexible dashboard and supports alerts as well. It offers system health monitoring as well, so you if you're looking to collect metrics from your app as well it would be a good fit.

If you prefer free then you can check out Nagios Log Server, ELK, Graylog etc. They will take more time to setup but are free. Splunk is free for up to 500MB / day, but is probably overkill.